# SPARQL Speed up federated query

Tags: query-optimization, sparql, wikidata, graphdb, federated-queries

I have my own dataset and I want to perform a federated query in SPARQL. Here is the query:

```
PREFIX : <http://myURIsNamespace#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

select * where { 
    ?bioentity :hasMutatedVersionOf ?gene .
    ?gene :partOf wd:Q430258 .

    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { 
        ?gene p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .

        ?gene p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>21000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)  
    }

}
```

I run the query via graphDB SPARQL interface but it's really really slow. It takes more than a minute to return 8 records. If I split the query in two parts, they are ridiculously fast.

**Query#1**

```
select * where { 
    ?bioentity :hasMutatedVersionOf ?gene .
    ?gene :partOf wd:Q430258 .          

}
```

56 records in 0.1s

**Query#2**

```
select * where { 
     SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { 
        ?gene p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .

        ?gene p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>21000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)  
    }       

}
```

158 records in 0.5s

Why the is the federation so slow? Is there a way to optimize the performance?

Comment: In this particular case, you could place `SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {...}` first, i. e. before `?bioentity :hasMutatedVersionOf ?gene`. On my data, this variant is 10 times faster. It seems that GraphDB performs 56 separate queries to Wikidata in your variant

Comment: @StanislavKralin Whoa! I belived that the query plan was not dependent on the way the query is written (like it happens for SQL). Do federated queries represent a good solution for this kind of problems? It seems faster to  perform 2 separated querires and then joining data locally.

Comment: @superciccio14 well you're right, it shouldn't be, but keep in mind that SQL engine developers have had considerably longer to iron out the wrinkles. You may have hit a case where GraphDB's query planner has a glitch.

Comment: @superciccio14, [order matters](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Order_Matters). In GraphDB, you can view plan explanation [in this way](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/explain-plan.html). It is hard to form effective plan in case of federated queries, since selectivity of "remote" patterns is unknown.

Comment: As to your general question. Federated queries are appropriate, when both "local" and "remote" resultsets are "small". Federated queries are inappropriate, when both resultsets are "large". When local resultset is large and remote resultsets is small, federated queries are appropriate, if "merging" performed locally. When local resultset is small, but remote resultset is large, federated queries are appropriate, if merging performs remotely _and_ queries to remote endpoint are optimized by your local engine (e. g. a single query with `values` is performed instead of many separated queries).

Comment: @StanislavKralin I confirm that I solved simply inverting the order of the two parts (if you want to answer, I'll accept your reply). I did not know that order matters in SPARQL. Thanks!

Comment: @superciccio14, I had tested my query before commenting :-). BTW, how many times the "inverted" query is faster on your data? Are your initial query performing faster on other triplestores/endpoints than on GraphDB (haven't you tested)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I was sure you've already tested. It was just a confirmation : ) The new query is really faster, very close to the single endpoints performance. In 2 seconds, I have the resultset. I did not test other triplestores different from GraphDB. Do you think that Blazergraph, or other stores, could perform even better?

Comment: Different stores will perform differently, and some won't care about the order of your clauses -- as some will test the result set sizes to optimize execution ("cost-based optimization") when building their execution plan.

Comment: @TallTed is there documentation that explains that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short answer

1. Just place your `SERVICE` part first, i. e. before `?bioentity :hasMutatedVersionOf ?gene .`
2. Read a good article on the topic (e. g. [chapter 5](https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/%7Estaab/Research/Publications/2010/LOD-Federation.pdf) of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-17551-0?view=modern))

Relevant quote from the aforementioned article:

> **3.3.2    Query Optimization and Execution**
>
> The execution order of query operators significantly influences the overall query evaluation cost.
> Besides  the  important query execution time  there  are  also  other
> aspects in the federated scenario which are relevant for the query
> optimization:

> **Minimizing communication cost.** The number of contacted
> data sources directly influences the performance of the query
> execution due to the communication overhead. However, reducing the
> number of involved data source trades off against completeness of
> results.
>
> **Optimizing execution localization.** The standard query
> interfaces of linked data sources  are  generally  only  capable of
> answering  queries  on  their  provided data. Therefore, joins with
> other data results usually need to be done at the query issuer. If
> possible at all, a better strategy will move parts of the result
> merging operations to the data sources, especially if they can be
> executed in parallel.
>
> **Streaming results.** Retrieving a complete result
> when evaluating a query on a large dataset may take a while even with
> a well optimized execution strategy. Thus one can  return results as
> soon as  they become available, which can  be optimized by trying to
> return relevant results first.

### Long answer

**Example data**

```sql
PREFIX : <http://myURIsNamespace#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

INSERT { ?gene rdf:type owl:Thing } 
WHERE {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { 
        ?gene p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        ?gene p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>26000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)  
    }
}
```

The total number of triples is 79. Please note that `26000000` is used instead of `21000000`.

**Query 1**

```sql
PREFIX : <http://myURIsNamespace#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT * WHERE {
    ?gene rdf:type owl:Thing .
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { 
        ?gene p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        ?gene p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>20000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)  
    }
}
```

**Query 2**

```sql
PREFIX : <http://myURIsNamespace#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT * WHERE {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { 
        ?gene p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        ?gene p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>20000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)  
    }
    ?gene rdf:type owl:Thing
}
```

**Performance**

|  | Query 1 | Query 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GraphDB | 30 sec | 1 sec |
| Blazegraph | 1 sec | 1 sec |

**GraphDB behaviour**

Executing Query 1, GraphDB performs 79 distinct `GET` requests to Wikidata¹:

[image: Wireshark — packets]

[image: Wireshark — statistics]

These requests are queries of this kind:

```sql
SELECT ?start ?statement ?end ?statement2 WHERE {
        <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18031286> p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18031286> p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>20000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)
```

---

It seems interesting, that on another machine, GraphDB performs `GET` requests of another kind:

```
GET /sparql?queryLn="Sparql"&query=<original_query_service_part>&$gene=<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18031286>
```

In this request, [Sesame protocol](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/sesame/system/ch08.html#d0e247) is used, these bindings in URL are not a part of [SPARQL 1.1 Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/).

Perhaps the exact kind of a request depends on the value of the internal `reuse.vars.in.subselects` parameter, which default value is presumably different on Windows and on Linux.

---

**Blazegraph behaviour**

Executing Query 1, Blazegraph performs single `POST` request to Wikidata²:

```sql
SELECT  ?gene ?statement ?start ?statement2 ?end
WHERE {
        ?gene p:P644 ?statement; 
              wdt:P31 wd:Q7187 ;
              wdt:P703 wd:Q15978631 ;
              wdt:P1057 wd:Q430258 .
        ?statement ps:P644 ?start .
        ?statement pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        ?gene p:P645 ?statement2. 
        ?statement2 ps:P645 ?end .
        ?statement2 pq:P659 wd:Q20966585 .
        FILTER (xsd:integer(?start)>20000000 && xsd:integer(?start)<30000000)  
    
}
VALUES ( ?gene) {
( wd:Q14908148 ) ( wd:Q15320063 ) ( wd:Q17861651 ) ( wd:Q17917753 ) ( wd:Q17928333 )
( wd:Q18024923 ) ( wd:Q18026347 ) ( wd:Q18030710 ) ( wd:Q18031220 ) ( wd:Q18031457 )
( wd:Q18031551 ) ( wd:Q18031832 ) ( wd:Q18032918 ) ( wd:Q18033094 ) ( wd:Q18033798 )
( wd:Q18034311 ) ( wd:Q18035006 ) ( wd:Q18035085 ) ( wd:Q18035609 ) ( wd:Q18036516 )
( wd:Q18036676 ) ( wd:Q18037580 ) ( wd:Q18038385 ) ( wd:Q18038459 ) ( wd:Q18038737 )
( wd:Q18038763 ) ( wd:Q18039997 ) ( wd:Q18040291 ) ( wd:Q18041261 ) ( wd:Q18041415 )
( wd:Q18041558 ) ( wd:Q18045881 ) ( wd:Q18047232 ) ( wd:Q18047373 ) ( wd:Q18047918 )
( wd:Q18047966 ) ( wd:Q18048744 ) ( wd:Q18049145 ) ( wd:Q18049164 ) ( wd:Q18053139 )
( wd:Q18056540 ) ( wd:Q18057411 ) ( wd:Q18060804 ) ( wd:Q18060856 ) ( wd:Q18060876 )
( wd:Q18060905 ) ( wd:Q18060958 ) ( wd:Q20773708 ) ( wd:Q15312971 ) ( wd:Q17860819 )
( wd:Q17917713 ) ( wd:Q18026310 ) ( wd:Q18027015 ) ( wd:Q18031286 ) ( wd:Q18032599 )
( wd:Q18032797 ) ( wd:Q18035169 ) ( wd:Q18035627 ) ( wd:Q18039938 ) ( wd:Q18041207 )
( wd:Q18041512 ) ( wd:Q18041930 ) ( wd:Q18045491 ) ( wd:Q18045762 ) ( wd:Q18046301 )
( wd:Q18046472 ) ( wd:Q18046487 ) ( wd:Q18047149 ) ( wd:Q18047491 ) ( wd:Q18047719 )
( wd:Q18048527 ) ( wd:Q18049774 ) ( wd:Q18051886 ) ( wd:Q18053875 ) ( wd:Q18056212 )
( wd:Q18056538 ) ( wd:Q18065866 ) ( wd:Q20766978 ) ( wd:Q20781543 )
}
```

**Conclusion**

With federated queries, it is hard to create effective execution plan, since selectivity of remote patterns is unknown.

In your particular case, it should be not very important, whether to join results locally or remotely, because both local and remote resultsets are small. However, in GraphDB, joining results remotely is less effective, because GraphDB does not reduce communication costs.

---

¹ For screenshots creation, `<http://query.wikidata.org/sparql>` instead of `<https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>` was used.

² In Blazegraph, one might write `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None"` to ensure sequential evaluation.

Comment: Great answer :)

Comment: See also GraphDB [9.5](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.5/standard/release-notes.html) release notes. Perhaps GDB-4493 and GDB-3043 make some improvements.

Comment: Correct, GDB-4493 implements batching with default "blocksize" of 15 (i.e. 15 VALUES are sent in each query). I just posted GDB-6485 to document this feature properly and how to control the blocksize.