# Querying a vector of strings to Wikidata using WikidataQueryServiceR

Tags: r, sparql, wikidata

Provided a vector of movies' names, I would like to know their genres querying Wikidata.

Since I am a R user, I have recently discovered [WikidataQueryServiceR](https://github.com/bearloga/WikidataQueryServiceR) which has exactly the same example I was looking for:

```
library(WikidataQueryServiceR)
query_wikidata('SELECT DISTINCT
  ?genre ?genreLabel
WHERE {
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424.
  ?film rdfs:label "The Cabin in the Woods"@en.
  ?film wdt:P136 ?genre.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}')

## 5 rows were returned by WDQS
```

Unfortunately, this query uses a static text, so I would like to replace `The Cabin in the Woods` by a vector. In order to do, I tried with the following code:

```
library(WikidataQueryServiceR)

example <- "The Cabin in the Woods" # Single string for testing purposes.

query_wikidata(paste('SELECT DISTINCT ?human ?humanLabel ?sex_or_gender ?sex_or_genderLabel WHERE {
  ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?human rdfs:label', example, '@en.
  ?human wdt:P21 ?sex_or_gender.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  OPTIONAL { ?human wdt:P2561 ?name. }
}', sep = ""))
```

But that does not work as expected, as I get the following result:

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Bad Request (HTTP 400).`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to output your SPARQL query? —

- There is no space after `rdfs:label`
- There are no quotes around `The Cabin in the Woods`

In your R code, instead of

```
  ?human rdfs:label', example, '@en.
```

line 7 should be:

```
  ?human rdfs:label "', example, '"@en.
```

---

Although `query_wikidata()` can accept vector of strings, I'd suggest to use SPARQL 1.1 [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) instead, in order to avoid too many requests.

```r
library(WikidataQueryServiceR)

example <- c("John Lennon", "Paul McCartney")

values <- paste(sprintf("('%s'@en)", example), collapse=" ")

query <- paste(
  'SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?human ?humanLabel ?sexLabel {
       VALUES(?label) {', values,
      '} 
       ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
       ?human rdfs:label ?label.
       ?human wdt:P21 ?sex.
       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
   }'
)  

query_wikidata(query)
```

For large number of `VALUES`, you probably need to use  the development verion of WikidataQueryServiceR: it seems that only the development version supports POST requests.

Comment: Your answer works great! You're right, I forgot those quotes and spaces.

I do not understand your second part of the answer regarding SPARQL values, though.

Comment: @ccamara, SPARQL 1.1 `VALUES` is a way to provide inline data. This allows to perform a single large query instead of many small ones ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45433716/7879193) is slightly related).

Comment: However, if query is large, then request should be POST, not GET. WikipediaQueryServiceR [provides](https://github.com/bearloga/WikidataQueryServiceR/issues/6) support for POST requests in the development version. However, I'm still receiving `Request-URI Too Long (HTTP 414)`, when, for example, `example <- 1:1000`. Possibly Wikidata does not allow such large requests even they are POST. See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T112151